# What is the correct assembly name for 'Window' C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, compilation

Im trying to compile some code in my application and its throwing me this error

```
The type or namespace name 'Window' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I've fixed the other errors that it promped me, I just had to add the reference
like so..

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
```

but I cant seem to figure out which assembly I need to add for 'Window'

Source code

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;


namespace SimpleBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// store code
    /// select what features
    /// print out textfile with all the code from the features
    /// compile that textfileContent to a exe
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fakeMessageOne()
        {
            if(fakeMessageCheckbox.IsChecked == true)
            {
                fakeMessage1 fkmsg = new fakeMessage1();
                fkmsg.fakeMessage();
            }
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {



            CSharpCodeProvider csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", frameworkTextbox.Text } });
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, outputTextbox.Text, true);
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Net.dll");

            CompilerResults result = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sourceTextbox.Text);
            if (result.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                result.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => errorTextbox.Text += error.ErrorText + "\r\n");
            }
            else
            {
                errorTextbox.Text = "--- Build Succeeded! ---";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Code im trying to compile

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;


namespace SimpleBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// store code
    /// select what features
    /// print out textfile with all the code from the features
    /// compile that textfileContent to a exe
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fakeMessageOne()
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Window`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx) class is in `PresentationFramework.dll`.

Comment: Solution is presented on the duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21621583/209578

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I wouldn't consider that a duplicate as you would only likely stumble across that if you were using the fully qualified name of the Window type; System.Windows.Window

Comment: I consider it as a duplicate since the solution for the original probably fits this one as well.

Comment: That doesnt work, seems to be the wrong one because its throwing me this  `Metadata file 'PresentationFramework.dll' could not be found`